# If SOCl2 reacts with alcohols via SNi, why doesn't POCl3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

A bit of a follow-up to [Why is thionyl chloride preferred for preparing alkyl chlorides from alcohols?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/60729/27806).

---

The reaction with $\ce{SOCl2}$ is also used instead of $\ce{PCl3}$ and $\ce{PCl5}$ when **retention of stereochemistry** is required. Phosphorus trichloride and phosphorus pentachloride both lead to *inversion*.

[image: SNi mechanism with thionyl chloride. (Chemsketch)]

The mechanism proceeds via a [$\mathrm{SN_i}$ pathway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNi), or **i**nternal nucleophilic substitution. This step has been highlighed in red; an [intimate ion pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intimate_ion_pair)$^{[\text{see below}]}$ is given in square brackets. Adding a nucleophilic solvent such as pyridine considerably increases inversion with $\ce{SOCl2}$ via an attack at the sulfur atom. Green marks blocking of the intramolecular substitution; blue is for inversion.

[image: Thionyl chloride with pyridine. No SNi. (Chemsketch)]

---

- **As far as I know, $\ce{POCl3}$ has not been seen following an $\mathrm{SN_i}$ mechanism (even *without* pyridine). Why?**

If possible, please provide a qualitative mechanistic reason. Something that is readily explained by *waving hands*. Regardless of whether such an approach is achievable, quantitative (calculational) answers are also most welcome.

---

**References discussing intimate ion pair formation**

- F. A. Carey, R. J. Sundberg. $(2007)$. *Advanced Organic Chemistry
  Part A: Structure and Mechanisms*, $4$th edition, pp 269$-$276. **ISBN:** [0-306-46242-7](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387448978)
- W. A. Hughes, E. D. Cowdrey, C. K. Ingold, S. Masterman, A. D. Scott. 'The Mechanism of Elimination Reactions. Part 1. Unimolecular Olefin Formation from Alkyl Halides in Bulphur Dioxide and Formic Acid'. *Journal of the Chemical Society*, $(1937)$, 1271$-$1277. **DOI:** [10.1039/JR9370001271](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/JR9370001271)
- E. S. Lewis, C. E. Boozer. 'The Kinetics and Stereochemistry of the Decomposition of Secondary Alkyl Chlorosulfites'. *Journal of the American Chemical Society*, $(1952)$, 74, 308$-$311. **DOI:** [10.1021/ja01122a005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01122a005)
- D. J. Cram. 'Studies in Stereochemistry. XVI. Ionic Intermediates in the Decomposition of Certain Alkyl Chlorosulfites'. *Journal of the American Chemical Society*, $(1953)$, 75, 332$-$338. **DOI:** [10.1021/ja01098a024](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01098a024)
- C. C. Lee, A. J. Finlayson. 'Rearrangement In The Reaction Between Thionyl Chloride And $3$-Methyl-$2$-Butanol. *Canadian Journal of Chemistry*, $(1961)$, 39(1): 260$-$261. **DOI:** [10.1139/v61-030](http://dx.doi.org/10.1139/v61-030)
- C. C. Lee, J. W. Clayton, D. G. Lee, A. J. Finlayson. 'Rearrangement Studies With $\ce{^14C-XIII}$: The Thermal Decomposition Of $1$-$\ce{^14C}$-$2$-Butyl Chlorosulfite'. *Tetrahedron*, $(1962)$, 18 1395$-$1402. **DOI:** [10.1021/ja01098a024](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01098a024)
- H. Patin, G. Mignani, C. Mahe, J-Y. Le Marouille, A. Benoit, D. Grandjean. 'Ferrocenyltrithiocarbonates: I. Direct access from α-ferrocenylcarbinols by a $\mathrm{SN_i}$ mechanism. Absolute x-ray structure determination of (*R*)-ferrocenylmethylmethane *S*-methyl-trithiocarbonate'. *Journal of Organometallic Chemistry*, $(1980)$, 193, 1, 93$-$103. **DOI:** [10.1016/S0022-328X(00)86079-9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-328X(00)86079-9)
- J. L. Kice, G. C. Hanson. 'Mechanisms of SNi reactions. Effect of aralkyl group structure on ion-pair return in the decomposition of aralkyl thiocarbonates'. *Journal of the American Chemical Society*, $(1973)$, 38 (7), 1410$-$1415. **DOI:** [10.1021/jo00947a037](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jo00947a037)
- M. B. Smith. $(2013)$. *March's Advanced Organic Chemistry: Reactions, Mechanisms, and Structure*, $7$th edition, pp 311, 486$-$487, 490, 598, 1316. **ISBN:** [978-0-470-46259-1](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470462590.html)
- <sub>*The $\mathrm{SN_i}$ (substitution nucleophilic internal) mechanism: retention of configuration*. [Powerpoint presentation](https://www.docenti.unina.it/downloadPub.do?tipoFile=md&id=566332), Università degli Studi di Napoli Federico II.</sub>
- <sub>James. *$\ce{SOCl2}$ and the $\mathrm{SN_i}$ Mechanism*. Master Organic Chemistry, *Alcohols*. [webpage](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/)</sub>

Comment: Hopefully, the subscript letter $\mathrm{i}$ in $\mathrm{SN_i}$ is clearly visible, and so is not to be confused with $\mathrm{SN_1}$. (I for one initially thought it was a typo when I learned about it in December.)

Comment: I don’t like the mechanisms as drawn due to the $\ce{S=O}$ double bonds which should be $\ce{\overset{+}{S}-\overset{-}{O}}$, but still $+1$ for a good question.

Comment: @Jan I'll see what I can do about it after school tomorrow ;)

Comment: @Jan I have updated the mechanism to include more delocalisation and true ionic bond character (both with dashed lines). Sadly, this has made the mechanism a bit harder to follow but is still alright. If there's anything amiss, feel free to ping me.

Comment: How is the reaction using thionyl chloride providing the product from retention? The chloride is attacking the activated alcohol from the back side, correct? Whether it's intramolecular or intermolecular is irrelevant.

Comment: Furthermore, what is the evidence that thionyl chloride delivers the chloride intramolecularly? That is a difficult mechanistic challenge.

Comment: @jerepierre The attack actually occurs from the same side as the oxygen. Probably there is also considerable ionic character to the $\ce{C-O}$ bond but I did not add it because $(1)$ could not draw it with both geometry and ionic character in mind, $(2)$ an ionic intermediary would require a solid reference which I was unable to find. So your counterarguments are definitely on point, and as soon as there's a better citable alternative I will edit :)

Comment: In order for the chloride to attack from the same side as the oxygen, it has to attack *through* the oxygen. Retention of configuration typically arises from two sequential inversion processes.

Comment: @jerepierre Does it [have to attack through oxygen though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opOOS.png) ;) (made with all-powerful computational software Chemsketch). I don't think two consecutive inversions better explains the experimental evidence at hand than $\mathrm{SN_i}$.

Comment: @jerepierre , No there is no $Cl-$ ion in the reactants. The $Cl-$ that was expelled from $R-(OH+)-SOCl2$ will immediately abstract proton from  $R-(OH+)-SOCl$  thus forming HCl. This is the main reason why $SOCl2$ with **pyridine** will give inversion pdt (since pyrindine being a weak base will abstract the proton instead of $Cl-$) . The $Cl-$ will then attack by $S_N2$

Comment: Is there a source that mentions any reaction by $\ce{POCl3}$ without pyridine? I think pyridine is important catalyst in that reaction. Also with pyridine it can never show $S_ni$ because pyridine helps the chloride ion to act as a leaving group with it's protonated form stabilizing it. And also @Jdeep makes the other point of this argument

Answer (score 4):

The step in the red box is wrong. You probably get dissociation to form an ion pair. The pair quickly collapses, leading to chloride attack on the cation before any dissociation or diffusion occurs so that you get the retention of stereochemistry.

For phosphorus based chlorination, this ion-pair mechanism is probably not favorable, though it's not clear to me *why* this is the way it is.

Comment: Actually in the process of editing that step (or considering at least). A ton of references will be added in a second. (There are also places where the ion pair is said to be 'not completely dissociated', and where it is not included.)

Comment: Zhe is right. It is a common misconception to write this mechanism as a direct displacement which is actually impossible on stereoelectronic terms.

Comment: There's just no way for the intramolecular $\mathrm{S}_{N}2$ reaction as written to take place, from a stereoelectronic perspective. There's probably some give on how tight the ion pair has to be though it has to be tight enough to explain retention. But we're in a gray area where mechanistic probes are probably going to be quite difficult.

Comment: @Zhe Yeah, the final sentence hits the nail on the head. ---- If the chlorine in the red box attached to sulfur has significant ionic character, wouldn't that make the "one-step" method (that I currently have) more probable? (as a last resort, I'm a bit too lazy to rewrite the mechanism again at the moment :D)

Comment: It's still probably not one-step. The proposed transition state for a front side $\mathrm{S}_{N}2$ reaction seems unlikely. Therefore, I would think that we have (at least) two steps though the barriers would be quite small...

Answer (score 1):

Once the alcohol attacks the SOCl2 the proton on the oxygen is more acidic because S is more electronegative than P.

What is likely happening is that R-OH-SOCl has a lower pKa than 5.2 (the pKa of the conjugate acid of pyridine), giving the chlorine time to do a nucleophilic attack.

Then R-OH-POCl2 should a pKa close enough to 5.2 that the equilibrium results in a low enough concentration of deprotonated R-O-POCl2 that the Cl- cannot find any. Since the elimination reaction is practically irreversible all of the R-OH-SOCl will be consumed well before the Cl- has a chance to find anything to react with
.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).