# Mechanism for the formation of an alkyl halide from alcohol and phosphorus trihalide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

I was reading about synthesis of alkyl halides from $\ce{PX3}$. I want to know the mechanism for this reaction. According to Solomons and Fryhle, no rearrangement takes place in case of $\ce{PBr3}$ , which leads me to think that the mechanism is S<sub>N</sub>2. But what about phosphorus bromides and iodides?

A Google search confirmed that the mechanism for reaction with phosphorus tribromide is indeed S<sub>N</sub>2, but I could not find anything on trichlorides and iodides. I need help for those.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think they may be different?

Comment: HBr undergoes AMK addition to an alkene in the presence of peroxide whereas other hydrogen halides do not. I think that anything is possible in chemistry and I do not want to make a mistake if a tricky question based on this appears in my exam.

Comment: The HBr is quite different from the phosphorus halides as there is no protonation step on the alcohol

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/if-socl2-reacts-with-alcohols-via-sni-why-doesnt-pocl3

Comment: Thanks for the links @Mithoron ! The reaction with $PCl_3$ looks like S_N^2 or S_N^i to me but I can't quite tell which. Which one is it?

Comment: I would assume that since the other answer suggests PCl3 gives the inverted product, it occurs via SN2.

Comment: see https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2015/03/20/pbr3-and-socl2/ (see step 4)