# Mechanism of Darzen's Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was dealing with Darzen's Reaction for the preparation of alkyl chlorides.
$$\ce{R-OH ->[SOCl2][Pyridine] R-Cl}$$
Now I encountered this as the mechanism of the reaction
$$\ce{R-OH + SOCl2 -> RO+HSO^-Cl2 ->[-Cl^-] R-O+HSOCl ->[NC5H5]R-O-SOCl}$$
$$\ce{R-O-SOCl ->[NC5H5][-Cl^-] ROSON+C5H5 ->[Cl^-] R-Cl}$$
My question is that why does the reaction in the second line occur? In other words, why does $\ce{R-O-SOCl -> ROSON+C5H5}$? I am unable to find any reasons to explain why this reaction would be favourable. What major factor allows pyridine to displace the chlorine atom?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/if-socl2-reacts-with-alcohols-via-sni-why-doesnt-pocl3

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for the post! But could you please elaborate on the stability of $\ce{ R-O-SOCl}$ in comparison to $\ce{ROSON+C5H5}$?